# Error Installing Python

Tags: python, linux, command-line, centos

Upon hitting

`make install`

I get the following error

`/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file /usr/local/bin/python2.6: Permission denied make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1`

I am not the root user so I assume its a permissions issue. I do have my own subfolder at `/home/my_username` Is there a way to complete the python installation there by giving a more specific command perhaps?

Also Python 2.4 is already installed how do I ensure that I am actually using 2.6?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Try to get the `sudo` password or ask your sysadmin to do it. This might also be a better question on SuperUser or ServerFault

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `configure` script lets you specify `--prefix=[dest]`. From the usage:

> By default, `make install' will install all the files in
>   /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib etc.  You can specify
>   an installation prefix other than /usr/local using --prefix,
>   for instance --prefix=$HOME.

So to install under `py26` in your home directory:

```
% ./configure --prefix=$HOME/py26
..
% make install
% $HOME/py26/bin/python
```

To use this on a more permanent basis, add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH` variable in your `~/.bashrc` (or other shell rcfile).  To verify which Python you're using, do this:

```
% which python
/home/user/py26/bin/python
```

---

Make sure you don't have a typo in the `--prefix` or the assignment to `PATH`.  For example:

```
% which python
/usr/bin/python

% ls -1 $HOME/py26/bin/python*
/home/user/py26/bin/python
/home/user/py26/bin/python2.6
/home/user/py26/bin/python2.6-config
/home/user/py26/bin/python-config

% export PATH=$HOME/py26/bin:$PATH
% which python
/home/user/py26/bin/python
```

Comment: the which python command still gives usr/bin and not home/user/py26/bin/python was i supposed to do something more?

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to show how to set the PATH. These commands work on my machine, under both zsh and bash.

Comment: I really appreciate your help..but this works when I export PATH from within the terminal...but does not work when i edit the .bashrc. I am 100.1% sure that there's no typo in my entry into the bashrc file. I ran source .bashrc and logged out and in....no luck

Comment: Very strange. The above syntax works perfectly on my system. You might want to ask a question on serverfault to get help debugging the bash startup sequence, e.g. something on the system may be resetting your `$PATH`.