# How to run Python 3.6 without $HOME/py36/bin/python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.6, linux-mint

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm using Mint 18.1. I installed Python 3.6 from its source code but it failed.

- if I enter `python`, version 2.7 runs.
- if I enter `python3`, version 3.5 runs (both were preinstalled with my Mint)
- if I enter `python3.6`, i get a 'command not found' error.

Then I found and followed [Error Installing Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131560/error-installing-python).

My question is how to do i set it up so python3.6 runs without having to enter `$HOME/py36/bin/python` in the terminal.

Thanks

---

edit

NEVERMIND. got it. thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: This question fits better at superuser.stackexchange.com or unix.stackexchange.com 

See this question, for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an alias in your shell's config file (`.bash_profile` or similar, if you're using bash) that points `python3` to `$HOME/py36/bin/python`.

To do this, you need to find your shell configuration file (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`) and edit it so that it contains an alias. Aliases take the form of `newcommandname='oldcommandname -flags'`, so you want something like `python3="$HOME/py36/bin/python"`. Note how there are no spaces around the equals sign, and double quotes, as that is required for this to work.

Alternately, you could add `$HOME/py36/bin/` to your `$PATH` variable, so that your shell automatically looks there for binaries. You can do this by editing your shell configuration file like above to say `PATH="$HOME/py36/bin/:$PATH"`. This makes your shell look here for executables before anything else; `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/py36/bin/"` will cause your shell to look for executables here after looking everywhere else. I don't recommend this, tbh; do the first one.

Comment: could you please explain exactly how i'm supposed to do that? sorry, this is all VERY new to me and i'm not familiar with any of it yet. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the above so that it contains that info. I'm going to assume you're using bash.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maintain several different versions of python is via conda, which allows you to create a variety of environments with different Python versions and packages. Conda is part of the Anaconda scientific Python distribution.

[Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/anaconda-overview)

There are lots of tutorials on YouTube and the web.